# Issue when std::cin to std::string with spaces

Tags: c++, string, cin

Just started learning C++ and encountered an issue with strings while doing an exercise.

So I initialized `std::string phrase;` while allowing the user to input and save the phrase to the string with `std::cin >> phrase;`. Now my issue comes when the inputted phrase has spaces, I noticed that the computer will only save the characters up till the first word only.

With the phrase `"sunsets are great"`, the `phrase.size()` only came out to 7, so the following words after the first space were not saved.

The entire exercise is supposed to compare all of the letters in the whole inputted string with another set of values. Should I be using a different function for this?

Comment: Do you want to read the line or the words? You can use `std::getline` to read lines or `while (std::cin >> phrase)` to read the words in a loop.

Comment: `std::cin.getline()` may do what you're asking for.

Comment: @Mansoor `std::cin.getline()` reads the input into a C string. `phrase` is a `std::string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also had this problem when i was first starting out.
whenever you want to read a string i would use the getline.

ie

```
string phase
cout << "enter phase" <<endl;
getline(cin,phase);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Works perfectly now! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take an entire line including space(s), you may use the following code:

```
string str; // declaration
getline(cin, str);
```

Remember: `cin.get` and `cin` will trim all the inputted characters just after first space.

Enjoy.